# Is such a cast possible?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
int main() {

 class A {
    public:
    static double test_code(const A& a);
  };

   class B : public A {
   public:
   B(int i) { };
   static double test_code2(const B& b);
   };

A::test_code(2);
B::test_code2(2);

return 0;

}
```

cf : http://ideone.com/ilfE8

The first method call will not compile, while the second will. Is there any way to make this conversion work? thanks

Comment: Can you declare a class inside the main?

Comment: What are you expecting to convert to what?

Comment: "Is there any way to make this conversion work?" Conversion from `2` to `A`? Not without specifying a derived type with a relevant constructor as a parameter (e.g., `B(2)`) or a relevant constructor in `A`.

Comment: @CodingMash MSVC 2012 does not complain about the class being inside `main()`. It says `local class` but no errors.

Comment: Right. Possibly OP is not using that.

Comment: well a big issue is that you are calling test_code with a integer value while it expects a value of class A. Try making a class A object and using that to call test_code. Similar problem applies to test_code2. Also you shouldn't declare classes inside methods. Firstly I don't think it's possible, secondly it makes reading your code in the future less fun and reusable.

Comment: @CodingMash: You can declare types inside functions, yes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Use `B` as a conversion to generate an `A` object out of an `int`?

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas : exactly

Comment: @ Benjamin Danger Johnson : it is possible to declare classes inside methods, cf the ideone links. which also proves that test_code2 is not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that cannot be done for an implicit type conversion. There are multiple reasons for that, the simpler is that for that to be an option the compiler would have to know at the place of call about all possible types that extend `A` and then check whether any/all of them can be implicitly converted from an `int`, resolve potential ambiguities... note that *all* types extending from a given type is an open set that can be extended *after* the current translation unit has been built!

You can achieve something alike that in different ways, like for example creating a function that takes the `int` and returns an `A` object, or explicitly creating the `B`. But none of them allow for an implicit conversion (i.e. without modifying the code to explicitly request the path for the conversion).

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine,

```
int main()
{
    class A {
    public:
        A(int i)
        {}
        static double test_code(const A& a) { return 0.0; }
    };

    class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int i)
            : A(i) {}
        static double test_code2(const B& b) { return 0.0; }
    };

    A::test_code(2);
    B::test_code2(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah but the whole point is that I don't want A to have the constructor you added

Comment: Well, then it is not possible. C++ is a language with its pre-defined rules. It cannot just read your mind.

Comment: @lezebulon - if that is the "whole point", it should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @lezebulon: To some extent it is. The question was not properly stated (*I cannot modify the base class* or something alike should be in the question).